# Point drawed over texture doesn't get the desired colour

Tags: c++, opengl, qt4, qtopengl

**Important:** I have to work with the **fixed pipeline** (I have no voice in this matter).

I have to modify some existing `OpenGL` code (a panoramic picture viewer, where the panorama is split into the six faces of a cube) so we're able to draw lines/points on top of the loaded textures, where the points are the mouse coordinates unprojected to object coordinates.

I wrote a test program with a coloured cube just to try the line painting on top of it:

[image: Test program]

I got this with the code pushing the *GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT* attribute to the stack, disabling it before painting the points and poping the stack attribute after I have done with the painting.

I tried to use that same approach in the existing application, but I got these results (here, I'm trying only to paint a point):

[image: Point over texture, 1]

[image: Point over texture, 2]

I specified *red* as the color for the point but, as you can see, it doesn't have the desired one. I thought it might be due to blending and that it might be mixing its color with the underlying texture, so I pushed the *GL_BLEND* attribute to the stack as well and disabled it before painting, but the point isn't getting the desired color anyway.

What is happening here? Is there a way to "force" the pipeline to paint the point red?

**initCube() :** this is call before updating the GL scene.

```
 void panoViewer::initCube() {
    makeCurrent();
    if(texture){
        glDisable( texture );
        textName = 0;
        texture = 0;
    }

    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S );
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T );
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R );

    glFrontFace( GL_CCW );
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    texture = GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP;
    textName = texnms[1];
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glTexGenf( GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_REFLECTION_MAP );
    glTexGenf( GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_REFLECTION_MAP );
    glTexGenf( GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_REFLECTION_MAP );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R );

    // Add the textures to the cube faces.
    // ...
 }
```

**initializeGL() :**

```
 void panoViewer::initializeGL() {
    qglClearColor(Qt::black);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

  // create texture objects
    glGenTextures( 1, textName );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textName );

  // find the largest feasible textures
    maxTex2Dsqr = maxTexSize( GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D, max2d, max2d );
    maxTex2Drec = maxTexSize( GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D, max2d, max2d / 2 );
    maxTexCube = maxTexSize( GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, maxcube, maxcube );

  // constant texture mapping parameters...
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
  // for cube maps...
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

  // enable alpha blending for overlay
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    // Create display list: dispList
    // ...
 }
```

**paintGL() :**

```
 void panoViewer::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(texture) {
        glBindTexture(texture, textName);
        glEnable( texture );
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
        glRotated( 180, 0, 1, 0 );   // camera looks at the front of the van
        glRotated( 180, 0, 0, 1 );   // van's roof points to the sky

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

//    double hFOV, vFOV;    // angular size at sphere center (deg)
//    double minFOV, maxFOV; // limits on vFOV
//    double wFOV;  // vert angle at eye (deg) sets magnification

    double  hhnear = Znear * tan( 0.5 * RAD(wFOV) ),
            hwnear = hhnear * aspectRatio,
            dxnear = 2 * hwnear * fcompx,
            dynear = 2 * hhnear * fcompy;

    glFrustum( -(hwnear + dxnear), hwnear - dxnear,
               -(hhnear + dynear), hhnear - dynear,
               Znear, Zfar
              );
    glRotated( 180, 0, 1, 0 );
    glTranslated( eyex, eyey, eyez );

    glRotated( tiltAngle, 1, 0, 0 );
    glRotated( panAngle, 0, 1, 0 );
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glCallList(dispList);

    glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        // Paint the point in red
        // ...
    glPopAttrib();
}
```

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that the code is based in `Qt`. It uses the `QtOpenGL` module extensively.

**UPDATE #2:** I've added some code.

Comment: This is all blind guessing without code, but one possibility is that lighting is enabled. Try `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi It didn't work. As for the code, I wasn't the one who wrote it, I was just handed it so I don't really know which parts are important. Should I post the `paintGL` method (see update)? The method where the textures are created?

Comment: Another option might be that texturing is on and set up in a way that ignores the input color. YOu could try disabling `GL_TEXTURE_2D` (for any texture unit potentially in use).

Comment: Yeah! That worked. Post an answer, then.

Comment: @derhass I don't know if you'll read my other comment since I forgot to tag you in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fixed function pipeline, there are many states which could lead to the vertex color beeing completely ignored.

As Reto Koradi pointed out in the comments, when lighting is enabled, the colors have no effect (unless `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` is enabled, in which case the color value is used to update the material parameters used for the lighting equation.)

As I pointed out in the comments, another case is texturing. Depending on the `GL_TEX_ENV_MODE` selected, the fragment's color (as determined by lighting, or directly interpolated from the vertex colors) is modulated by the texture color, or completely replaced. In that case, disabling texturing for every texture unit in use can solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Disabling the texture units while drawing the point solved the issue!